# How to experiment with Xcode on OS X 10.4x

Tags: xcode, osx-tiger

I'd like to start experimenting with Cocoa, Objective-C and Xcode, but the only Apple computer I own is an old PowerBook with OS X 10.4.7 installed and as far as I can tell I would have to buy and install OS X 10.5 (Leopard I think) just to be able to install Xcode 3.2 - the currently available version. The thing is I'm a Windows developer and I don't want to have to upgrade this barely functional Mac laptop just to be able to play around with Xcode. So, I'm wondering is there any way that I can download some older 2.x version of Xcode that will run on OS X 10.4.7?

Comment: Actually, 3.2 is only available on Snow Leopard (10.6) which is Intel-only. Leopard will run 3.1.x, but 2.5 is reasonable close to modern (it's from 2007, and was released alongside 3.0 which required 10.5) and should give you a flavor of Xcode. While you're at it, run software update to get your PowerBook to 10.4.11... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a free account at Apple Developer Connection at http://connect.apple.com (if you haven't already) and in the Developer Tools subsection of Downloads (about halfway down) you will find:

> Xcode 2.5 Developer Tools
>
> Xcode 2.5 is an update release of
>   Xcode developer tools, providing bug
>   fixes over Xcode 2.4.1. Xcode 2.5 can
>   be installed on Tiger (Mac OS X 10.4)
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

Does your Tiger DVD have XCode on it? I know that Leopard DVDs include the then-current version of XCode.

You can also download XCode 2.1 tools from the ADC section on developer.apple.com. ADC -> Downloads -> Mac OS X.

You'll have to create an account but it's free for basic ones.

Comment: Your suggestion would have worked except the installation gave me an error saying that it couldn't open the XCodeTools.mkpg file (scratched disk probably). Is there some archive on the web where I might be able to download XCode 2.x?

Comment: OS X DVDs all come with dev tools on it. Bummer the disk is scratched... The accepted answer already mentioned this: go to http://connect.apple.com and register for a free account if necessary. Once logged in, click on Downloads, then Developer Tools in the right sidebar. On that page, you can just search for "2.5" and you'll see it.